# Sleeping a Thread in Canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

In my game I want to draw the screen black after losing or winning a level and then draw a message in white on to the screen. After a few seconds delay I then want the screen to disappear when touched. Below is part of my draw() method. The problem is that screen freezes (or the thread sleeps) before the screen is drawn black and the text is drawn, even though the sleep command is after the text and canvas is drawn. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
if (state == WIN || state == LOSE){
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        message = "Touch Screen To Start";                                                
        canvas.drawText(message + "", mCanvasWidth / 2, mCanvasHeight / 2, white);
        try {
        GameThread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This won't fix your problem, but rather a small nitpick: `Thread.sleep(...)` is a static method, so don't call it on a Thread instance but rather on the class.

Comment: Are you sure that's what you're observing? A half second delay might be hard to discern. If you put like a 5 second delay, will your canvas draws still come after your delay?

Comment: BTW, I think 500 is probably not the right about of time.  I think its in milliseconds.

Comment: Consider a countdown timer instead as i have posted below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling that the canvas function doesn't actually display anything until it returns.  Especially if you are running on Android >3.0 with hardware acceleration, or any configuration with double buffering, it won't actually update the screen until it finishes.

Instead when you draw the black screen, store the current time.  Something like:

```
mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Then in the function watching for presses, check how many seconds have passed and see if enough time is happening, something like:

```
if( (System.currentTimeMillis() - mStartTime)/1000 > 5){
    //Put code here to run after 5 seconds
}
```

This should draw your text and avoid blocking the Ui thread (a big no no in every respect).

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it. Any idea why were not supposed to block the UI thread? It really wouldn't harm my program I don't think...

Comment: The Ui thread is generally where the system communicates with your app.  That design is repeated in just about every toolkit I've dealt with.  If you block it, Android has no idea if you are blocking on purpose, or are crashing and the user needs to kill you (see the halting problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).  Thus any time you block it, Android gets upset cause it doesn't know what you are doing.  It also built assuming you wont, which is good for things like performance.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the call to drawText is taking a few fractions of a second longer than you realize, and since you immediately call sleep, you are actually sleeping the thread before you draw.

Try putting a small loop, for( i < 10000 ) or something before the call to sleep and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use CountDownTimer

```
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html


 new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     // Here you do check every second = every 1000 milliseconds
 }

 public void onFinish() {
    // Here you can restart game after 30 seconds which is 30K milliseconds.
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
}.start();
```

Comment: The way this works is onTick() gets called very second until the 30 seconds are up.  At which point onFinish() gets called.  I think this should work fine.  You can restart anyting in onFinish, and keep checking every second. Its totally configurable.